# I am gettting Error in my output Python in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, error-handling, pylance

whenever I save a .py file, even if it's new, I get an error in my output window... I think is because of Pylance but I can use it without a problem.

I am new in Python and I don't really know how to fix that.

This is the message I get:

"""

User belongs to experiment group 'pythonaacf'
User belongs to experiment group 'pythonSendEntireLineToREPL'
User belongs to experiment group 'pythonNotDisplayLinterPrompt'
User belongs to experiment group 'pythonTensorboardExperimentcf'
User belongs to experiment group 'ShowExtensionSurveyPrompt - enabled'
User belongs to experiment group 'CollectLSRequestTiming - control'

> conda --version
> pyenv root
> python3.7 c:\Users\jvald.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.658691958\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python3.6 c:\Users\jvald.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.658691958\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python3 c:\Users\jvald.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.658691958\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python2 c:\Users\jvald.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.658691958\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python c:\Users\jvald.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.658691958\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> py -3.7 c:\Users\jvald.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.658691958\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> py -3.6 c:\Users\jvald.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.658691958\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> py -3 c:\Users\jvald.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.658691958\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe c:\Users\jvald.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.658691958\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> py -2 c:\Users\jvald.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.658691958\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> ~\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe info --json
> Error 2021-03-17 13:12:00: Detection of Python Interpreter for Command py and args -2 failed as file Python 2 not found!

-3.9-64
-3.8-64
-3.6-64 does not exist
Error 2021-03-17 13:12:00: Detection of Python Interpreter for Command py and args -3.7 failed as file Python 3.7 not found!

-3.9-64
-3.8-64
-3.6-64 does not exist
Python interpreter path: ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Starting Jedi Python language engine.

> ~\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe info --json
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe c:\Users\jvald.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.658691958\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py pylint --disable=all --enable=F,unreachable,duplicate-key,unnecessary-semicolon,global-variable-not-assigned,unused-variable,unused-wildcard-import,binary-op-exception,bad-format-string,anomalous-backslash-in-string,bad-open-mode,E0001,E0011,E0012,E0100,E0101,E0102,E0103,E0104,E0105,E0107,E0108,E0110,E0111,E0112,E0113,E0114,E0115,E0116,E0117,E0118,E0202,E0203,E0211,E0213,E0236,E0237,E0238,E0239,E0240,E0241,E0301,E0302,E0303,E0401,E0402,E0601,E0602,E0603,E0604,E0611,E0632,E0633,E0701,E0702,E0703,E0704,E0710,E0711,E0712,E1003,E1101,E1102,E1111,E1120,E1121,E1123,E1124,E1125,E1126,E1127,E1128,E1129,E1130,E1131,E1132,E1133,E1134,E1135,E1136,E1137,E1138,E1139,E1200,E1201,E1205,E1206,E1300,E1301,E1302,E1303,E1304,E1305,E1306,E1310,E1700,E1701 --msg-template='{line},{column},{category},{symbol}:{msg}' --reports=n --output-format=text "d:\012_PYTHON\Udemy\004.Postgree and SQL\02.Start Postgree\psycopg2-binary.py"
> cwd: d:\012_PYTHON\Udemy\004.Postgree and SQL
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe c:\Users\jvald.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.658691958\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py pylint --disable=all --enable=F,unreachable,duplicate-key,unnecessary-semicolon,global-variable-not-assigned,unused-variable,unused-wildcard-import,binary-op-exception,bad-format-string,anomalous-backslash-in-string,bad-open-mode,E0001,E0011,E0012,E0100,E0101,E0102,E0103,E0104,E0105,E0107,E0108,E0110,E0111,E0112,E0113,E0114,E0115,E0116,E0117,E0118,E0202,E0203,E0211,E0213,E0236,E0237,E0238,E0239,E0240,E0241,E0301,E0302,E0303,E0401,E0402,E0601,E0602,E0603,E0604,E0611,E0632,E0633,E0701,E0702,E0703,E0704,E0710,E0711,E0712,E1003,E1101,E1102,E1111,E1120,E1121,E1123,E1124,E1125,E1126,E1127,E1128,E1129,E1130,E1131,E1132,E1133,E1134,E1135,E1136,E1137,E1138,E1139,E1200,E1201,E1205,E1206,E1300,E1301,E1302,E1303,E1304,E1305,E1306,E1310,E1700,E1701 --msg-template='{line},{column},{category},{symbol}:{msg}' --reports=n --output-format=text "d:\012_PYTHON\Udemy\004.Postgree and SQL\02.Start Postgree\psycopg2-binary.py"
> cwd: d:\012_PYTHON\Udemy\004.Postgree and SQL
> ~\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe env list
> ##########Linting Output - pylint##########

"""

This is my Settings Json:

```
{
"jupyter.askForKernelRestart": false,
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "meta.function-call.generic",
            "settings": {
                "foreground":"#2ecde2"
            }
        }
    ]
},
"workbench.colorTheme": "Solarized Dark",
"window.zoomLevel": 1,
"editor.mouseWheelZoom": true,
"editor.quickSuggestions": true,
"workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
"indentRainbow.colors": [


    

    "rgba(255,255,64,0.03)",
    "rgba(127,255,127,0.03)",
    "rgba(255,127,255,0.03)",
    "rgba(79,236,236,0.03)"
],
"workbench.editorAssociations": [
    {
        "viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
        "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
    }
],
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
"emmet.extensionsPath": "",
"php.validate.run": "onType",
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\jvald\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\",
```

}

Thank you

This is a ScreenShot

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using other python language services (Jedi, Microsoft)?  Please provide us with examples that can minimize the recurrence of this problem.

Comment: No I haven´t used Jedi. I don´t really know how to minimize this message... Whenever I set up my output for Python (instead of code) I get that message. I can still work without a problem but I don't think is normal getting that message.

I am using Code Runner, indent-rainbow- Pylance- vscode-icons but no many more...

I have edited the main question with a screen shot. Let's see if that helps

Thank you very much

Comment: -Please try to reinstall the "python" extension and reopen VS Code to check whether it is the same.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the information you provided, they show the process of VS Code loading related extensions, loading language services, and executing python scripts, and so on.

Please try to reinstall the "[Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)" extension and reopen VS Code.